# Why can't I reach a computer by name?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a Windows 2003 domain controler that also provide DHCP and DNS services. We were always able to ping (or access more usefull services) a server by using only it's name, like this :

```
ping MyServer
```

Suddenly, on a (Windows Vista **Home**) computer the server can no longer be reached this way. However I can still ping the server by its IP adresse of by using the FQDN :

```
ping 192.168.0.56
ping MyServer.MyDomain.net
```

The user of this computer thinks this behavior started after an update of antivirus program AVG.

What could cause the DNS resolution to fail for the computer name and at the same time work for the full path?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the DNS settings of the computer??

Comment: Yes, I did check. The DNS server is my domain controler.

Answer (score 3):

DNS suffix settings would be my first check.

[image]

Make sure the computer in question is actually appending DNS suffixes at all, and make sure that it's got the correct DNS suffix for your domain, and isn't trying to append some other DNS suffix that it might have picked up at home or from an AVG update or where ever else.  If needed, manually input the DNS suffix for your domain into the list of DNS suffixes to append.

[commentary]
AVG, eeeeewww.
[/commentary]

Comment: For command line freaks: `powershell "Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=TRUE -ComputerName .| Select-Object -Property DNSDomainSuffixSearchOrder"`